# Scala implicit conversions that do not apply to certain types

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I have a container type that holds metadata associated with a value.

```
class Container[A](val value: Option[A], val meta: Metadata)
```

Sometimes it's useful to access the meta but most of the time it's more convenient to work with a value as if it was `Option[A]`.  There is an implicit conversion for this.

```
object Container {
  implicit def containerToValue[A](c: Container[A]): Option[A] = c.value
}
```

All of that works fine.  The issue is that often there will be an implicit conversion present from `A => B` and the value happens to be `Container[A]`.  What I'm looking to do is to provide a way to do an implicit conversion basically from `Container[A] => Option[B]`.  My first attempt was something to the effect of:

```
object Container {
  implicit def containerToValue[A](c: Container[A]): Option[A] = c.value
  implicit def containerToB[A,B](c: Container[A])(implicit conv: (A) => B): Option[B] = c.value.map(conv)
}
```

Scala didn't like that at all, so as a fallback since in 90% of the cases `B` will actually be a `String`, I tried doing something with more of the types filled out:

```
object Container {
  implicit def containerToValue[A](c: Container[A]): Option[A] = c.value
  implicit def containerToB[A](c: Container[A])(implicit conv: (A) => String): Option[String] = c.value.map(conv)
}
```

This did a little better but I got a number of errors about ambiguity.  What I was wondering is if there was a way to specify that `A` is not `String`.  Perhaps something like:

```
implicit def containerToB[A >!> String]
```

Such that I could tell the compiler this implicit conversion applies only when A isn't String.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: I know this probably isn't what you want to hear, but please reconsider—implicit conversions like this are scary stuff and there are almost certainly better ways to get the convenience you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing an implicit conversion (because they're hard to debug, cause runtime errors when you least expect them, and make the code generally less clear) why not add a type class to the mix so that you can work with things the way you want to work with them?

```
trait Extractor[A,B]{
  def opt(that: Container[A]): B
}
```

and then you explicitly create all the various instances that you might want to have:

```
def myGloriousFunction[B](that: Container[A])(implicit ex: Extractor[A,B]) ={
  val value = ex.opt(that)
  //more stuff
}
```

It'll handle the finding of the "extractor" for your inner `Option` and it's still fairly explicit in its signature.